# Exponential linear equations

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function

Can one find a closed form solution in $x$ to an equation such as:
$Ae^{ax}+Be^{bx}+c=0$, where $A, B, a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c<0$?

Thanks!

Comment: Substituting $\large e^x=u$, we have $\large Au^a+Bu^b+c=0$ which won't have a closed-form-solution in general.

Comment: However, there are series solutions.  See e.g. [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248529/compute-inverse-series-for-implicit-equation)